# How to secure client data where user should not be able to read

Tags: java, flash, networking, tcp

How to prevent client data. I have an application with secure connection which is web application running in flash and TCP connection. Where user hacks the data and publish it.

Server code --> Java.
Client code --> Flash

Steps:
 1. Hacker logins as real user and password by giving valid username via standalone application.
 2. Server passes data via TCP assuming real user.
 3. Hacker takes the data and publish it via his server.
[image]

How to prevent data from Hacker to publish

Comment: Once the hacker steals your data, unless the stolen data are encrypted, there is nothing you can do to keep him from doing anything he wants with the data. You need to focus on preventing the theft in the first place.

Comment: Data are encrypted by server and decrypted in flash. But client code is readable he takes the decrypt code and implemented in his app

Comment: If the hacker has access to the unencrypted data, you can do nothing. It's like someone stealing your cash; you can't prevent him from using your cash for whatever he wants to use it on.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding *"...he takes the decrypt code and implemented in his app."* did you consider code **obfuscation** to make it harder to read & implement in some new app?

You can try **[IrrFuscator](http://www.ambiera.com/irrfuscator/features.html)** for protecting your SWF.

Also is **real user via browser** meaning someone using your own specific website? If so, why not have your server check if the data request comes from your own website's IP address (assume real user) or else if some other IP then assume it's coming from a hacker's app.

In any case, it's about checking who asking for data, if they're not from acceptable location then deny them the data so they always have to use your website. This should also block the current hacker since they login via their own app outside of your site...

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem here is Hacker creates a standalone application and request my domain via his application as real user valid user name and password. So data's are given to him now he publish the data. Tried obfuscation, blocking user, blocking IP but he register as new user or comes from new ip currently.

Comment: That standalone application is not your website, right? so why not block any server request that is not coming from your website? A simple logic like `IF request_source = "http://mywebsite.com" THEN {give data} ELSE {deny access}` That logic blocks everything except request via your website. You could even try it the login stage where you check & block if they logged via your website or block if not `true`. I don't use Java (you tagged Flash) so I can't give you Java code to test but you can search for this topic.

Comment: Also obfuscation wont stop that hacker now, just future people who don't **yet** know the decrypt code. Unless you change the SWF code completely and re-upload the obfusctated new version so that your hacker only knows the "old way" which is no longer valid... Also by IP, I mean of website not user machine. Think about http headers, tokens etc for extra security. Just make sure your server only accepts requests/logins from your website, not from external other apps/sites.